# Why do these two axios post methods have different result

Tags: express, axios

After two days of struggling finally i found the solution to fix it, But i'm not sure why it works.

I want to make a request to verify JWT in the server with axios so i did it simple like this

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth', {headers: {
   Authorization: 'Bearer ' + varToken
}})
```

But i got `undefined` Meanwhile when i tried it with Postman it worked fine i got the token in the headers of request.

I googled it all day and asked 3 stack overflow questions they all suggested me to specify `{ Content-Type: application, Accept: application }` But it didn't work.
Today i manage to make it works by setting axios like so

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/auth',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + varToken
  }
})
```

And it works! So my question is

What is the difference between these two axios config ? the first method which is technically being defined everything same as the second method why do i got undefined from it?

*server code

```
app.post('/auth', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.headers['authorization'])
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling the first one properly.  The [calling signature](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axiosposturl-data-config) for that one is:

```
axios.post(url[, data[, config]])
```

The 2nd argument is for `data`, not for config options.  If you're not going to pass any data (usually you would with a post), then you could do:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth', "", {headers: {
   Authorization: 'Bearer ' + varToken
}});
```

Comment: Yeah you're right! i thought if there's no data to pass than skipping that argument is acceptable. By the way thank you so much i will check thing like this carefully next time

Comment: @NathanP - If this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Comment: The reason you can't skip the argument is that both the data and the options can be objects so if you only pass one of them, axios doesn't know which is which so it assumes it's data.  You are not the first one to get bit by this.  I knew this one because I've seen others make the same mistake.